# Assigning randomly selecting and removing rows from a 2d matrix

Tags: matlab, variables, random, row

I have a 35x2 matrix containing stimlui for a word memory experiment.  With each run of my program I need to be randomly sampling 16 cells so that the experiment is always different.  I have managed to do this using datasample() to create an 8x2 matrix, however I need to remove them from the 35x2 to ensure they are not reselected in the second of two trials.  I know how to remove cells when the cell coordinates are known; but not when they are randomly selected each time.  Any advice would be gratefully accepted.

Thank you

Kelly

Answer (score 2):

`Datasample` returns the indices it selects. Consider this

```
  m = rand(35,2);             % // test matrix
  [s i ] = datasample(m,8,1); % // s are the samples, i are their indices
   m(i,:) = [];               % // elimination of selected samples
```